# Autowiring dependencies of domain classes

Tags: java, spring

Should autowiring or XML dependency configuration be avoided in the domain classes? Should I instead use `new`? Right now I am adding `@Component` and autowiring some of it's dependencies.

Comment: Imo, it depends on their scope.

Answer (score 2):

I try not to mix model with anything other than ORM dependencies.

Comment: Could you explain the cons and why you not bring Spring to the domain layer?

Comment: 1) It leads to complicated code.
2) It creates unnecessary dependency, which defeats the prupose of ORM architecture.
3) It is pretty much a useless idea to couple model components to anything other than entities.

Comment: @LuckyLuke: it does complicate things, and unnecessary dependencies should be avoided. but also it's because the business logic that belongs in entities is different from the business logic that belongs in services.

Comment: I was injecting another domain object. I know injecting objects from layers above domain complicate things and should not be done. However injecting domain objects into each other.

Comment: Better to inject object into a business layer and then set dependecy on domain objects via setters.

Answer (score 0):

It is an architectural decision.

If you decide to use rich domains models, these will have collaborators and spring has a good support to configure them. See this [springsource blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2008/01/23/new-improvements-in-domain-object-dependnecy-injection-feature/) for more information.

If you choose to use anemic domains models instead, you will have nothing to set on them.

There are a lot of discussion on the web about anemic vs rich domain models, so there is not a general rule, you need to choose one.

Comment: I was not injecting objects from higher layers into the domain layer object. I was just injecting one domain class into another. Like Car into Engine.

Comment: I don't see any problem injecting other models,  services or whatever you need if it makes sense in the model. Note that when looking for design rules, others may be trying to solve problems that you don't have.